# Is there a way to printing all cookie values inside my controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I set cookies like this inside my indexController

```
public function index()
{
   Cookie::queue('name',"$name", 60);
   Cookie::queue('id',"$cookie_id", 60);
}
```

now i need to retrive all cookies values in another controller is there is any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just call `Cookie::get()` without the `$name` parameter (untested).

Otherwise you can get it directly from the request:

```php
public function index(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    dump($request->cookies);
}
```